# Magento connect Manager will not unisntall an extesion

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect-manager

I used Magento Connect Manager to install this quick view extension called **Dolphin_QuickWatch**.  It installed, but I couldn't get to function, so i decided to remove it.  I went back to Magento Connect Manager and when I click on Uninstall it displays the Magento Connect Manger Log In page again instead of removing it (picture attached).

How Can I remove this extension and why is this happening? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to remove it without using magento connect.

1. please go to

```
app/etc/modules/Dolphin_QuickWatch.xml
```

2. Change active attribute to to `false`.

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dolphin_QuickWatch>
            <active>false</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Dolphin_QuickWatch>
    </modules>
</config>`

For your problem, please try to clear cache and remove /var/session folder, logout & login again.

Please try to check /var/log folder if there is any exception or error log related to QuickWatch extension.

Comment: I will give a try.  Any good quickview extension you could recommend that works with 1.9.1.1 and rwd theme?  Thank you.

Comment: There are many of them  from amasty, aheadworks, cmssmart ... but I have not used. You may search a theme that supports quickview too ( would save you time)

Comment: http://demo.amasty.com/quick-view/home-decor/electronics.html - does this work for you?